# Multiple occurrences with nothing in between

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find all occurrences of strings that start with **{:** and end with **:}**.

So from this:

> asdfasd{:ertwert:}tropibnmmnbmdf{:fg  h:}roptiouurtyo

I would get:

> {:ertwert:}

And:

> {:fg  h:}

And not:

> {:ertwert:}tropibnmmnbmdf{:fg  h:}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you've tried `{:.+:}` and it didn't work as you wanted.

[`{:.+?:}`](http://regexr.com/3dqhd) should do the job for you. This is because `+` is greedy by default, so it will capture as much as it can.  By adding a `?`, will makes it lazy and it will stop as soon as `:}` is found.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and especially the explanation. I had tried it exactly as you guessed, but it was the `?` that I couldn't figure out.